# sigmajs - curved edges in SVG Exporter

Tags: javascript, svg, sigma.js

I'm trying to get the SVG exporter (sigmajs) plugin to export curved edges as well.

Does anyone have any idea how I can approach this? I had thought about iterating over all edges and then changing the edge type, but without success so far.

Many thanks in advance!

Update:

In the file sigma.exporters.svg.min.js all edges are iterated at one place, my idea was to add the attribute edgetype (defaultEdgeType in sigma/docs) at this point and also set it to curve to have curved edges when exporting the result- doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Are you regenerating the graph before the export with `s.refresh();`? Here is an example with curved edges:
https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/examples/events.html

Maybe you could start with that and add the SVG export to it

Comment: Yup, am regenerating the graph with s.refresh(); but it still doesn't work.
I can't figure out how to add the edge-type option to also get exported. I'll update my question with some more details!